# set and check error level not works as expected in batch

Tags: batch-file, error-handling

Below is the sample logic for setting errorlevel and then checking the errorlevel.

```
echo setting error based on some condition
set errorlevel=2

if errorlevel 2 (
    echo Error logic 
)
```

Expected output was

> "Error logic"

Actual output : not printing anything on console

Comment: The %ERRORLEVEL% is one of the _dynamic variables_ provided by cmd.exe that you should never set. Other dynamic variable is %TIME%, so if you think that you never should do this: `set time=12:34:56` (because after that, the current %TIME% no longer works), then the same point apply to ERRORLEVEL (and all dynamic variables). You may use `cmd /C exit 2` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: "You can't just setup ERRORLEVEL variable". One of the way is

```
echo err = %ERRORLEVEL%
call :set_error_code 123
echo err = %ERRORLEVEL%

exit /b 0

:set_error_code
exit /b %~1
```

See more on [ERRORLEVEL](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).